# login using omniauth-facebook "undefined method `slice' for nil:NilClass" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth-facebook

i have a problem using omniauth-facebook. i tried to login in my rails app using facebook but its giving me an error and the env['omniauth.auth'] is throwing a nil value
 here is the error..

```
 NoMethodError at /auth/facebook/callback
 undefined method `slice' for nil:NilClass
```

here is my model

```
#fields
  field :provider
  field :uid
  field :name
  field :oauth_token 
  field :oauth_expires_at , type: DateTime

  #functions
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).find_or_initialize_by.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end
```

and this is my controller

```
  def create
    user = Usersfb.from_omniauth(ENV["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_url
  end
  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to root_url
  end
```

my routes.rb

```
  root 'main#index'
  get 'session/destroy' , to: 'session#destroy'
  get 'auth/:provider/callback' => 'session#create'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistake in controller action:

```
def create
  #user = Usersfb.from_omniauth(ENV["omniauth.auth"])
  user = Usersfb.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

[`ENV` it is environment variables](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/ENV.html) not `request.env`, this `ENV["omniauth.auth"]` return `nil`  and this `where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid))` trying slice `nil` that raise  `undefined method 'slice' for nil:NilClass` .

Answer (score 1):

request.env didn't work for me.
I added callback_path to omniauth initializer and it works now.
Here's how it looks like:

omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :facebook, APP_ID, APP_SECRET, callback_path: '/auth/facebook/callback'
end
```